# XCode - Always have to reset signing identities and re-download provisioning profiles

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, xcode7

I'm building mobile apps using Xamarin-Visual Studio. I have a MacBook Air that is my iOS build host.

Every day or two I have to reset my XCode signing identities, re-download my provisioning profiles, and then reboot the MacBook.  If I don't, I am unable to install the IPA on an iOS device (it creates an IPA file but just won't install to device).

Any ideas why?

XCode version is 7.3.1.  My setup was working fine for months.  It started doing this for no apparent reason about a week ago.  I'll also add that I have another build environment with an iMac that started doing the same thing at about the same time.

Absolutely nothing has changed with my Mac and Windows environments (although I'm not sure Windows/Xamarin have anything to do with this.  Seems like more of a glitch on the Mac side).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you manually installing the binary onto a device? As in with an Enterprise Distribution profile?

To add, if you're using the same team/account to sign on two separate computers, there may appear some problems with getting the provisioning profiles to work as intended.

Comment: Echoing what is said above, if you are sharing a signing identity with other team members, if another team member needs to use the singing identity, they will need to reset it and redownload the profile. And when they do, you will have to do the same when you need to use it again. Resetting the signing identity basically creates a new certificate (with the same name) and thus invalidates the profile that used the "old" certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Making comment above an answer since there has been no activity on this since:

If you are sharing a signing identity with other team members, if another team member needs to use the singing identity, they will need to reset it and redownload the profile. And when they do, you will have to do the same when you need to use it again. Resetting the signing identity basically creates a new certificate (with the same name) and thus invalidates the profile that used the "old" certificate.